# Bot Framework Azure Connection Provider for Sharepoint and Office365

Tags: azure, sharepoint, office365, botframework

how to complete these fields for SharePoint and Office365?
[image]

and

[image]

and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your bot is going to connect with both SharePoint and Office 365, you're better off using Azure Active Directory v2 as an OAuth2 provider and then utilizing the [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview?toc=./toc.json&view=graph-rest-1.0) (and [specifically for SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepoint?view=graph-rest-1.0)). This way, you only need one connection and there is significantly more help/support for this route.

You can [follow this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) for the authentication process.

There's also a sample bot for auth and msgraph: [C#](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/24.bot-authentication-msgraph) / [JS](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/24.bot-authentication-msgraph)

---

Another good reason to go the Graph route is because the [Discovery Service API will be deprecated in November 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/discovery-service-rest-operations) (regarding "Discovery URL" parameter for SharepointOnline connection).